# Export HBase Data to RDBMS

Tags: hadoop, hbase, sqoop

I am using HBase to store the data but later to suit my requirements I want to export the data from HBase to RDBM like mysql or postgres. I know we have Sqoop as a option but it imports from MySQL and put it into HBase and will export the saved data in HDFS to RDBMS and it cannot import data directly from HBase.

Is there any tool to export data from HBase tables to RDBMS tables?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is a better approach, but HBase data can be [exported](http://www.sethcall.com/blog/2010/04/10/how-to-export-and-import-an-hbase-table/) into a flat file and then loaded into RDBMS.

Comment: And to add to this, you can mount an HBase table as a Hive table (assuming it has a consistent schema): https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HBaseIntegration

Comment: @Praveen Sripati, your link and text are confusing. The link is to an article about exporting from HBase (answering exactly what the question asks!). But your text says it's Hive instead.

Comment: @PraveenSripati, I can export it to flat file but after that how would I load it to RDBMS? Is it there any tool or mechanism to achieve that?

Comment: Depends on the DB - for [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlimport.html).

Comment: @PraveenSripati, Thanks I have used LOAD DATA INFILE but it given me some junk+actual values as we don't the delimiter to use. What will be delimiter used for flat file export and how to avoid the junk?

Comment: @PraveenSripati your link is now dead (404). Can you update the link, or even better, add the information from the link to your answer so it does not depend on an external site.